# AzDO ManualValidation step failing in YAML pipeline with no explanation of why

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I'm converting to a full YAML AzDO pipeline and need to wait for manual validation for certain stages of my pipeline.  Added the new ManualValidation task into a serverless job, however it fails immediately with no details about why.  I did add a Delay task in there as well (just as a sanity check to make sure my serverless job was actually running successfully), and it runs fine.

```
- job: waitForValidation
  displayName: Wait for external validation
  pool: Server
  timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
  steps:
  - task: Delay@1
    inputs:
      delayForMinutes: '1'
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: |
        me@email.com
        you@email.com
      instructions: 'Please validate deployment can continue and resume'
      onTimeout: 'reject'
```

These are the docs I'm using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I also dropped into the GitHub project just to make sure the task is still version 0 (it is).

Suggestions on why this might be failing and/or ways I can get some more details in the pipeline about WHY it failed?

Comment: I tested with your script but it works perfectly on my machine. I would like to know if there are any error messages in your pipeline runs page? (Go to Pipelines -> Click your pipeline -> choose the failure run) Even something like "Job failed" can be useful. In addition, could you provide your complete YAML sample script? Or will it fail even if you just run the waitForValidation job?

Comment: Turns out this is only available in the cloud version of AzDO, we are using the server version - and it produces exactly zero error messages in the pipeline, which was really unhelpful - the least they could have done was throw a "not supported" type of error!  All our other steps and jobs passed successfully, it was just this one task on this one job failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we are actually using AzDO Server, not AzDO Services (thanks, Microsoft for naming them so similarly) and this task is not yet available in the Server version :(

For anyone also frustrated by this lack of functionality on-prem, here’s the documentation on using [Deployment Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) and some about [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops)

We are able to get most of the functionality we were looking for this way, thou it does require setting up environments.

Comment: @JaneMa-MSFT it's been 2 years and this is still not in Devops *Server*. Is that a dead project?